# JButton in Java swing

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Is there a way to check whether a button is enabled is set to true or false through code?

Answer (score 5):

boolean enabled = button.[isEnabled()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#isEnabled())

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you are not aware of it Sun has put all the documentation for their Java classes [online](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/). This should be your first port of call for questions on the Java SDK classes. For documentation on [JButton](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html). You are obviously welcome to ask questions here as well :)